# Send a message to 2 numbers using Twilio

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible to send a message to 2 numbers (or more) with Twilio?

I wrote a script to **scrape** some stock prices and send it to me by Twilio.

My question can I make it to send the same message for me and other people?

.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can send the same message to different people at different phone numbers! You would use Python code like this, replacing your account credentials with your own, the message to send, and the different phone numbers to send to.

```py
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
# DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = 'YOUR-ACCOUNT-SID'
auth_token = 'YOUR-AUTH-TOKEN'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
arr = ['PHONE-NUMBER-TO-SEND-TO', 'PHONE-NUMBER-TO-SEND-TO'] #you can add more to this array
for num in arr: #loop through phone numbers in array
    message = client.messages.create(
        body='Message to send to different people',
        from_='YOUR-TWILIO-PHONE-NUMBER', 
        to=num
    )
    print(message.sid)
```

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: What do u mean by saying this is insecure.? My account might get banned or something?

Comment: Copying and pasting your account credentials means that others could access it. Don't publish them to GitHub, mask them with environment variables, etc @ http://twil.io/secure. If this helped you please mark as answer!